# Extending Search Core Results with XSL

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution

I'm working on a webpart that extends `CoreResultsWebPart`. 
I have create new solution and added new **WebPart** project into it.

I got most of it working apart from XSL.

I want to use `this.XslLink` however, I'm not sure how to deploy my XSL file with my webpart (while keeping it as sandbox solution).

Do I need to create another feature (farm) just so I can deploy XSL file?

Comment: you can upload your xsl file to one of your document library.

Comment: this is exactly what I dont want to do. I want everything to be deployable as a solution rather than having to upload stuff in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provision the XSL file using a `Module` element and then reference that xsl file using a site relative url, like this:

```
<Module Url="Stylesheets">
    <File Path="MyModule\file.xsl" Url="file.xsl"/>
</Module>
```

and

```
<XslLink>Stylesheets/file.xsl</XslLink>
```

Comment: Thank Wictor. I would have to deploy this solution as farm solution then. How do you deploy a file to Style Library/XSL Style Sheets, rather than file system.

Comment: This exact code can be used in the sandbox

Comment: It comes up with **is not compatible with Sandboxes solution** error.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks. Instead of modifing elements file. I have added new project of type of **Module** which then deployed files fine.

Comment: Awesome Luke! That's a better approach!